# How to prevent special characters using event.keycode in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to know what is the exact event.keycode number values for below special characters
! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) .

I have the below code.

```
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116 || event.keyCode == 93 || event.keyCode == 33 ||
        event.keyCode == 34 || event.keyCode == 123 || event.keyCode == 154 ||
        event.keyCode == 82 || event.keyCode == 17 || event.keyCode === 38 ||
        event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 13 
     ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    
    
});
```

I want to use the above function and prevent the special characters from typing when using mobile devices.

I tried the below event.keycode numbers . But the same is not working.

```
        event.keyCode == 161 || event.keyCode == 64 || event.keyCode == 163 ||
        event.keyCode == 164 || event.keyCode == 165 || event.keyCode == 160 ||
        event.keyCode == 166 || event.keyCode == 171 || event.keyCode === 168 ||
        event.keyCode === 169
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Note: [`keyCode` has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Comment: Hi Andy , is there any other solution for the above issue. Kindly help thanks.

Comment: [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.key` property ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)) which will return the pressed key's character, and an array [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), we can significantly simplify this:

```js
const forbiddenChars = ['@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '.']

$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if (forbiddenChars.includes(event.key)) {
    console.log('Key prevented')
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: The problem is whenever i type as ! in the keyboard then the value of 1 is showing in the textbox.  The value is not displaying as !. but instead it is showing as 1 . Similarly if i type as @ then value is showing as 2. So how to prevent this .

Comment: @Mahi To be honest that sounds like a bug/problem with your mobile device's keyboard. Have you tried typing the same thing in a some sort of note-pad type app to see if the symbols appear correctly there? (If not, then the problem isn't related to your JS at all)

Comment: I am trying to enter values in OTP text boxes in my application using mobile device. So i have restricted to use only numbers but when i type as '!' then the value is getting as 1 . Other than this it is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would probably be with RegExp.

```
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
  if (!regex.test(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you want to only allow alpha-numeric latin characters, but bare in mind it will also prevent any other special chars, or other character sets.

Comment: Agreed. The regex might require adjustments if some special characters are to be allowed.